# Serializing an object to a JSON input stream using GSON?

Tags: gson

I'm not sure if I'm asking for a right thing, but is it possible to make the GSON `Gson.toJson(...)` methods family work in "streaming mode" while serializing to JSON? Let's say, sometimes there are cases when using `Appendable` is not possible:

```java
final String json = gson.toJson(value);
final byte[] bytes = json.getBytes(charset);
try ( final InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes) ) {
    inputStreamConsumer.accept(inputStream);
}
```

The example above is not perfect in this scenario, because:

- It generates a string `json` as a temporary buffer.
- The `json` string produces a new byte array just to wrap it up into a `ByteArrayInputStream` instance.

I think it's not a big problem to write a `CharSequence` to `InputStream` adapter and get rid of creating the byte array clone, but I still couldn't get rid of generating the string temporary buffer to use the `inputStreamConsumer` efficiently. So, I'd expect something like:

```java
try ( final InputStream inputStream = gson.toJsonInputStream(value) ) {
    inputStreamConsumer.accept(inputStream);
}
```

Is it possible using just GSON somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this comment](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/758#issuecomment-166610988), this cannot be done using GSON.